# Solving $\cos(ax) = C\cos(bx)+D\sin(bx)$

Tags: trigonometry

What is the process for solving an equation of the form:
$$\cos(ax) = C\cos(bx)+D\sin(bx)$$
for $x$?

Comment: There likely will need to be some constraints on the constants. I can think of a couple things to try: $$a\sin\left(cx\right)+b\cos\left(cx\right)=\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}\cos\left(cx-\arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\right)$$
for non negative $b$ (for negative $b$ just flip the sign) and $$(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2 = \cos(x)$$

Comment: If $C^2+D^2=1$, you may introduce $\theta$ such $\cos\theta=C$ and $\cos\theta=D$, so the equation becomes $\cos(ax) = \cos(bx-\theta)$, which is equivalent to $\pm ax \equiv bx-\theta \mod 2\pi$. There is no general method outside this particular case.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.